# Need to have pick list field values into a Visual force page from a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to get the Picklist values of the custom object into a visual force page? I tried using describe method but it isn't working, please help

Comment: Can you share with us what you have tried so far? Any error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. It will work.

```
List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = 
ObjectApiName.FieldApiName.getDescribe();

List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();

for (Schema.PicklistEntry f: ple) {
    options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));
}       

System.debug('picklist options are '+options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is your actual requirement.

In Visualforce page, if you use the standard `<apex:inputField>` or `<apex:outputfield>` tags to input or output fields,they respect the field's type and display it automatically and even get your picklist LOV's. All you have to do is use the standard controller for custom object. refer below :

```
    <apex:page standardcontroller ="CustomObject__c">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> GlobalMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
 Schema.DescribeSObjectResult obj = GlobalMap.get(objectName).getDescribe();
 Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = obj.Fields.getMap().get(objectField).getDescribe();
 List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
```

it works fine for me , i hope it helps you as well.